# SOAP API and invalid Field Type

Tags: soap-api, custom-field

We use SOAP-API and Perl to transmit data from our web shop to Salesforce and Financial Force. To save invoices and related line items we use FF objects `c2g__codaInvoice__c` and `c2g__codaInvoiceLineItem__c`.
I added new field `Cost_Price__c` to `c2g__codaInvoiceLineItem__c`. Field type is **Number (9,2)**. In SOAP WSDL it is defined as **xsd:double** (like all other price fields). When I try to transmit a line item with a decimal value for `Cost_Price__c` following error occurs:

```json
    {
        'success' => 'false',
        'errors' => {
            'fields' => 'Cost_Price__c',
            'statusCode' => 'INVALID_TYPE_ON_FIELD_IN_RECORD',
            'message' => 'Cost Price: value not of required type: 10.740658'
    }
```

The line item:

```json
    {
        'FF_Flat_fee__c' => 'false',
        'c2g__Product__c' => '01t90000001TRETAA4',
        'Discount__c' => '0.00',
        'c2g__DeriveUnitPriceFromProduct__c' => 'false',
        'Cost_Price__c' => '10.74',
        'c2g__TaxCode1__c' => 'a1d90000000ulx6AAA',
        'c2g__Quantity__c' => 1,
        'c2g__UnitPrice__c' => '15.24',
        'c2g__Invoice__c' => 'a0zN0000001eUEIIA2',
        'FF_Price_Before_Discount__c' => '15.24',
        'CurrencyIsoCode' => 'USD',
        'c2g__SetTaxCode1ToDefault__c' => 'false',
        'c2g__CalculateTaxValue1FromRate__c' => 'true',
        'c2g__LineDescription__c' => '2 Official TNUs'
    }
```

Why I can't store value 10.74 to a field of type  Number (9,2)?

Comment: Leaving the quotes didn't help either. Other values work with quotes too.

Comment: Odd. Is there any reason why it's sending `10.740658` instead of just `10.74`? I'm wondering if the four extra numbers are causing a problem.

Comment: Also, as you're using SOAP, is the `Cost_Price__c` field defined in the WSDL file?

Comment: yes, as xsd:double

Comment: Sorry, I misread that part of your question!

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that you're sending 6 numbers past the decimal instead of 2, but I'd be really surprised if that was the problem.

Comment: ok, I mixed upper and lower case in field definition (WSDL). It must be all lower case, even it is mixed in SF.

Answer (score 0):

"Why I can't store value 10.74 to a field of type Number (9,2)?"

Because the field type is Number (9,2) and you're sending 10.740658. That is Number(2,6)

Maybe a trigger is turning 10.74 to  10.740658